# Parse core doesn't show any data sent from Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

This is the same code from

https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing

Everything is done right, Android Studio recognizes Parse objects and everything, but when I run the app, it runs perfectly.. but no data is sent to parse.
Insted appid and userid I actually have real Keys.

```
 Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "appid", "userid");
        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();
```

has anyone had this problem? I cannot find a solution. I only have one app in Parse, so the Keys must be right.

Comment: You should add Parse logs and see what happens with: `Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);` before initialize Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so on your manifest you should include the name attribute on your application tag like this

```
<application
android:name="com.packname.MyApplication"

.../application>
```

where MyApplication is the class that contains app key and id that connects to parse